# .length showing value 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following form

```
<form name="client-login" method="post" onsubmit="return Check_form();">
  <label>Email</label><input type="text" name="client-email" value=""><br/>
  <label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password"  value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"">
</form>
```

And below is the javascript function `Check_form()`

```
   <script>
function Check_form()
{
    var email    = document.getElementsByName("client-email");
    var password = document.getElementsByName("password");
    alert(email.length);
    if(email.length == null)
    {
        email.style.border='1px solid red';
        return false;
    }
    else if(password.length == null)
    {
        password.style.border='1px solid red';
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
```

But despite me submitting with empty fields it is alerting value as 1 for the client email.
Any idea what is wrong.

Comment: [*getElementsByName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyname) returns a NodeList, whose length is an integer and therefore never *null*, so consider using `if (email.length == 0)` or `if (!email.length)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the above JS you have taken email variable which contains array of email text field named "client-email".

To check the email lentgh use this:

```
alert(email[0].value.length);
```

Comment: It is actually an array. The first index of the array contains the email text field object.

Comment: @jsve you are right that's why I have used 0 index. I have edited now I think this is good.

Comment: So is this a optimal solution?

Comment: @amit yes. as you have only one text field which this name. You can also use the id of text field you need to add the id in text field.

Comment: So that means getElementById is the better solution. Then when do we use getElementsByName?

Comment: @amit getElementsByName is used when there need to get the elements of name type having same name.

Comment: @jsve—[*getElementsByName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyname) returns a live [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not an array.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ—you don't need IDs on form controls. To get a reference to the input, you can use `document.forms['client-login']['client-email']`. If the control names are changed to valid identifiers, you could use say `document.clientLogin.clientEmail`.

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns nodeList.

Either use `document.getElementById()` or

you can use `document.getElementsByName("client-email")[0]` which will return the first element from that nodelist

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByName()` returns an array

So in your case use `document.getElementById()`